# Is it possible to expose multiple ports on one endpoint with Apache ODE?

Tags: web-services, bpel, apache-ode

I tried to expose multiple ports on one endpoint.
The bindings are equal - SOAP.

```
<service name="Test">
<port name="CustomerPort" binding="tns:BindingOne">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/ode/processes/Test" />
</port>
<port name="GuidePort" binding="tns:BindingTwo">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/ode/processes/Test" />
</port>
</service>
```

For some reason only one port is exposed.
In WCF this would work.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

ODE uses Axis2 for exposing Web services, so if it does not work, it is most likely a limitation of Axis2. Though, I'm not sure if it is a limitation at all, my gut feeling is that exposing two different ports at the same EPR is a bad idea.

Comment: Why should it be a bad idea? Isn't it just the idea of having different interfaces for one service at the same endpoint, which could serve different roles the service could be involved?

Comment: Hm, you're probably right. I haven't seen such a scenario in real world yet, all combined services I've seen so far have used different EPRs. In this case it might be a limitation of ODE since it [extracts](https://github.com/apache/ode/blob/trunk/axis2/src/main/java/org/apache/ode/axis2/hooks/ODEAxisServiceDispatcher.java) the service name from the EPR. If a SOAPActionBasedServiceDispatcher is invoked before, it may work.